# Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'PIHMS.DB.MySql.tbl_mas_diag_tests' to 'PIHMS.DataContracts.Master.put_diag_tests_OPDC'

Tags: .net, angularjs

objOutput.m_selected_diag_test = tmp_lst_diag_tests[0];

Not able to assign the first row of list to objOutput.m_selected_diag_test. I'm getting an error Cannot implicitly convert type . What should i do.
here is code:

```
[DataContract]
    public class get_diag_tests_OPDC:BaseClass_DC
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<put_diag_tests_OPDC> ml_diag_tests { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public put_diag_tests_OPDC m_selected_diag_test { get; set; }

        public get_diag_tests_OPDC()
        {
            ml_diag_tests = new List<put_diag_tests_OPDC>();
            m_selected_diag_test = new put_diag_tests_OPDC();
        }
    }
```

This is the DB connection Code:

```
                rc = tmp_dbc.Select(ref strErrorMessage, tmp_strWhereCondition, ref tmp_lst_diag_tests);
                if (rc < 0)
                {
                    objOutput.Status = "ResponcedWithError";
                    objOutput.ReturnMessage = strErrorMessage;
                    objOutput.ReturnValue = rc;
                    return rc;
                }

                //tmp_selected_diagtest = tmp_lst_diag_tests[0];
                objOutput.m_selected_diag_test = tmp_lst_diag_tests[0];
```